# Drinking water while standing vs seated

Tags: hydration

I have heard people suggesting to drink water when you are seated after a tiresome activity. They usually ask to avoid drinking water while standing upright.

Does that have an actual scientific reasoning, or is just baseless advice?

You could slam me for it being easy to google, and I have googled for it. But when we talk about trekking, climbing, swimming, cycling, etc... its a different situation. As a trekker or cyclist I'd be mad at me sitting periodically to get a sip of water.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Not to be picky, but: One vs other position would be better _for what?_  For which exact physical/health outcome? I believe, this should be a part of your question if you expect a scientifically reasonable answer. There can be a difference in speed of gastric emptying, but this alone may not be so important.

Comment: Is this a documented suggestion someplace? Or is this something your friends are saying just to tease you?

Comment: You have heard people say this, I have never heard anyone say this. Curious. If I've finished a game of squash and am done for the day, I'd say I'd drink sitting down. If I'm backpacking and still have more trail to cover I'll either sit or stand - moving around without the pack feels good with muscles getting stiffer. But that isn't about the water, more about keeping loose.

Comment: @James: Please see results for "why not to drink water while standing" on google.

Comment: @JonCuster: I wondered the same. But please see results for "why not to drink water while standing" on google.

Comment: Duplicate of https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58177/does-posture-matter-while-drinking-water ?

Comment: Spoiler - no, it doesn't matter...

Comment: And most of the rest are '8 shocking reasons why...' type web pages which pegs my BS meter

Comment: The question has been asked and at least partially answered here: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/27338/is-drinking-while-standing-unhealthy and here: https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/58177/does-posture-matter-while-drinking-water .

Comment: My father was taught 65 to 70 years ago: "A drink is worth to sit down." If you take a real break to have a drink, you may as well sit down. Not because of the drink itself. But if you have a sip of water while walking or cycling, go on with your activity as soon as you can, no need to make a break of every sip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No scientific basis. For it to be so, drinking would have to process differently standing up than sitting down. But if you sit upright then the upper body (where the water is being processed) is no different than if you were standing. So any effect must be from the waist down. But that would be an issue of general circulation most probably, rather than anything to do with drinking water. Note however that I am not a doctor and this is not medical advice.